# What is the difference between [profile] and [user-profiles]? Which to keep?

Tags: discussion, retagging

There are some questions [tagged with both [profile] and [user-profiles]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/profile+user-profiles). See also: [profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/profile) & [user-profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-profiles)

(Please note that I retagged some questions from [user-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-profile) to [user-profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-profiles) as per Ask a SU mod cr)

Comment: [tag:profile] is used also in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/387358/can-a-motherboard-bios-profile-be-used-to-disable-devices), where it is referring to BIOS profiles. I am not saying it is correct (or not correct) usage; if [tag:profile] should be a synonym of [tag:user-profiles], then the questions should be tagged individually.

Comment: Also [tag:monitor]+[tag:profiles], [Tag:color-profiles]. [Tag:e-mail]+[Tag:profiles] [Tag:chrome]+[Tag:profiles] other software + "profiles" etc. Might require keeping the word [Tag:profiles] seperated. Then good combos [Tag:roaming-profiles] & [Tag:network-profiles] (good on its own). The move from [Tag:user-profile] to [Tag:user-profiles] great. Keeping A single [Tag:user-accounts] is a good move there is also [Tag:user-account] . Dumping profiles off of multi tagged ok.

Comment: Searching for "profile" tags, I noticed that most of them have no description, thus no aid for the user to decide which to use. Also there exist `profile`, `.profile` and `profiles` (among others). That should be cleaned up, really!